# Bootstrap Dropdown elements disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I am using bootstrap with the dropdown. When I first load the page, all elements appear in the list, but for the second time, there is not any element in the list. When I open the page in incognito tag, elements again appear,

Here are the source codes,

Thanks in advance,

JS;

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "db/../..",
    dataType : "json"
  })
    .done(function( result ) {
      if ( typeof result.error !== "undefined" ) {
        // Error
        dialog.close();
        alertDialog( "Hata", result.error, BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER );
      } else if ( typeof result.List !== "undefined" && $.isArray( result.List ) ) {
        // A proper result
        if ( result.FirmList.length < 1 ) {
          // No records found
          dialog.close();
          alertDialog( "Error", "Nothing Found!", BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING );
        } else {
          // Parse details
          var f = result.List;

          for ( var i = 0; i < f.length; i++ ) {
            var op = document.createElement( "option" );
            op.value = f[ i ].Id;
            op.textContent = f[ i ].Name;

            document.getElementById( "List" ).appendChild( op );
          }

          $( "#select" ).chosen();

        }
      } else {
        dialog.close();
        alertDialog( "Error", "No Idea!", BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER );
      }
    })
    .fail(function(a, b, c) {
      dialog.close();
      alertDialog( "Error",
        "Error",
        BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER );
    });
```

HTML;

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="List" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count>1">
</select>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/o86yk3z1/)

Comment: I take it you are using chrome. Try ctrl+shift+del and clear your cache. It should work, then. Tell me if it doesn't.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding when i see document.createElement( "option" ); while you are using jQuery...
We need a js fiddle to help you.

Comment: @DanielHarrin Thank you, it works, but after 5 6 times refreshing the page, the same problem occurs, no elements appear in the list

Comment: @Loenix I am very new at jQuery, If you have any suggestion, I am open and willing to take your advices, thank you

Comment: jQuery is able to declare a DOM element by declaring HTML in it `$("<option></option>")` You get a jQuery object with option in it, you can put it where you want and apply properties or event to it.

Comment: Please post a sample of the data you expect from the AJAX call.